# Why won't this Javascript code increment by 1?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code that, once upon a time, worked fine for incrementing and decrementing the input value by 1 when the + or - buttons were clicked. I changed a couple of things (design wise) but can't seem to target the input anymore. Any help would be great!

HTML CODE

```js
    addRoom.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let input = e.target("#addRoom").querySelector("#rooms_amount");
            input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
        });
    });

    subtractRoom.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let input = e.target.closest("#subtractRoom").querySelector("#rooms_amount");
            input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;

        });
    });
```

```html
<div id="center_counters_wrap">
        <small class="smallTitle">Bedrooms</small>
        <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">

            <div class="roomsWrap">
                <div class="data-increase" id="addRoom">+</div>
                <div id="subtractRoom">-</div>
                <input class="data-value" id="rooms_amount" value="0" placeholder="0" type="number" autocomplete="off"
                    placeholder="0" required>

            </div>


        </div>

        <small class="smallTitle">Bathrooms</small>
        <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
            <div class="roomsWrap">
                <div id="addRoom">+</div>
                <div id="subtractRoom">-</div>
                <input id="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

            </div>


        </div>

        <small class="smallTitle">Kitchens</small>
        <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
            <div class="roomsWrap">
                <div id="addRoom">+</div>
                <div id="subtractRoom">-</div>
                <input id="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

            </div>
```

Comment: Hit F12 and read the error messages.

Comment: **Looks like a typo.** `e.target("#addRoom").querySelector("#rooms_amount")` tries to call a DOM element (`e.target`) as though it were a function. That will fail. I suspect you meant to have `.closest` in there, as you do with `subtractRoom` (which is why I think it's a typo, not a misunderstanding).

Comment: @Pac0 how can you turn code into executable when variables on foreach are not declared?

Comment: @Pac0 - The OP's code presumably has `addRoom` and `subtractRoom` variables that shadow the automatic globals.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute [***`id`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, use [***`class`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute instead. You also should target the closest element *.roomsWrap* and find the element *.rooms_amount* to update the value.

Try the following way:

```js
let addRoom = document.querySelectorAll('.addRoom');
let subtractRoom = document.querySelectorAll('.subtractRoom');

addRoom.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let input = e.target.closest('.roomsWrap').querySelector(".rooms_amount");
      input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
  });
});

subtractRoom.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let input = e.target.closest(".roomsWrap").querySelector(".rooms_amount");
      input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;

  });
});
```

```html
<div id="center_counters_wrap">
  <small class="smallTitle">Bedrooms</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">

      <div class="roomsWrap">
          <div class="addRoom data-increase">+</div>
          <div class="subtractRoom">-</div>
          <input class="data-value rooms_amount" value="0" placeholder="0" type="number" autocomplete="off"
              placeholder="0" required>

      </div>


  </div>

  <small class="smallTitle">Bathrooms</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
      <div class="roomsWrap">
          <div class="addRoom">+</div>
          <div class="subtractRoom">-</div>
          <input class="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

      </div>


  </div>

  <small class="smallTitle">Kitchens</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
      <div class="roomsWrap">
          <div class="addRoom">+</div>
          <div class="subtractRoom">-</div>
          <input class="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot have multiple id's in your DOM, change your input id's to classes and find the input by going to the first parentElement and then select the input of that parentElement.

Likewise, change your addRoom and substractRoom to classes as well so that you are properly able to find them in your DOM via querySelectorAll, after that you can easily loop through them and assign eventListeners to each of your +/- nodes.

Also, finding the closest element could produce bugs later when adding code so it's better to rely on classes. Find the input using querySelector and search by the given class.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.addRoom').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let input = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.rooms_amount')
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.substractRoom').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let input = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.rooms_amount')
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;

  });
});
```

```html
<div id="center_counters_wrap">
  <small class="smallTitle">Bedrooms</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">

    <div class="roomsWrap">
      <div class="addRoom" class="data-increase">+</div>
      <div class="substractRoom">-</div>
      <input class="rooms_amount" value="0" placeholder="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

    </div>


  </div>

  <small class="smallTitle">Bathrooms</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
    <div class="roomsWrap">
      <div class="addRoom">+</div>
      <div class="substractRoom">-</div>
      <input class="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <small class="smallTitle">Kitchens</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
    <div class="roomsWrap">
      <div class="addRoom">+</div>
      <div class="substractRoom">-</div>
      <input class="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Eugen! Since im new to JS i really appreciate these in-depth answers, they're alot of help.

Comment: @DelroyBrown, please note, multiple class attribute in the same element will ignore all the classes except specified the first one (*data-increase* will not work in the above answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of mistakes.

1. You are using same `id` for all `+` & `-`. id should be unique. In this case you can use class.
2. Secondly you are using `closest` which traverse up towards the parent. So with only closest you cannot get the input. In this case you can use either `parent` or `closest` and then use `querySelector` to find the input

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.addRoom').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let input = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".rooms_amount");
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.subtractRoom').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let input = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".rooms_amount");
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;

  });
});
```

```css
.addRoom,
.subtractRoom {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addRoom {
  color: green;
}

.subtractRoom {
  color: red;
}

.addRoom:hover,
.subtractRoom:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center_counters_wrap">
  <small class="smallTitle">Bedrooms</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">

    <div class="roomsWrap">
      <div class="data-increase addRoom">+</div>
      <div class="subtractRoom">-</div>
      <input class="rooms_amount" value="0" placeholder="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

    </div>


  </div>

  <small class="smallTitle">Bathrooms</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
    <div class="roomsWrap">
      <div class="addRoom">+</div>
      <div class="subtractRoom">-</div>
      <input class="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

    </div>


  </div>

  <small class="smallTitle">Kitchens</small>
  <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
    <div class="roomsWrap">
      <div class="addRoom">+</div>
      <div class="subtractRoom">-</div>
      <input class="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer i really appreciate it. Still trying to wrap my head around things with JS so its always helpful to get a response like this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const addRoom = document.querySelectorAll("#addRoom");
  const subtractRoom = document.querySelectorAll("#subtractRoom");
  addRoom.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let input = e.target.closest(".roomsWrap").querySelector("#rooms_amount");
            input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
        });
    });

    subtractRoom.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let input = e.target.closest(".roomsWrap").querySelector("#rooms_amount");
            input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;

        });
    });
```

```html
<div id="center_counters_wrap">
        <small class="smallTitle">Bedrooms</small>
        <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">

            <div class="roomsWrap">
                <div class="data-increase" id="addRoom">+</div>
                <div id="subtractRoom">-</div>
                <input class="data-value" id="rooms_amount" value="0" placeholder="0" type="number" autocomplete="off"
                    placeholder="0" required>

            </div>


        </div>

        <small class="smallTitle">Bathrooms</small>
        <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
            <div class="roomsWrap">
                <div id="addRoom">+</div>
                <div id="subtractRoom">-</div>
                <input id="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

            </div>


        </div>

        <small class="smallTitle">Kitchens</small>
        <div id="bedrooms_counter_wrap">
            <div class="roomsWrap">
                <div id="addRoom">+</div>
                <div id="subtractRoom">-</div>
                <input id="rooms_amount" value="0" type="number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0" required>

            </div>
```

Comment: multiple id's in your html? this is not the way to go